# Creating an associative array from Wordpress $wpdb->get_results

Tags: php, wordpress

It's been a long day and for some reason this is totally eluding me...

My Wordpress database request looks like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

And the output looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ([id] => 2 [organisation] => Company 2 ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ([id] => 1 [organisation] => Company 1 ) 
)
```

I need to turn it into an array that looks like this:

```
Array ([1] => Company 1, [2] => Company 2)
```

This must be dead easy, but I just can't see it for some reason...Grateful for any pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array();
foreach ($results as $res){
    $array[] = $res->organisation;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Why dont you just request as an array in the first place

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
```

return will be an array. if its one level deeper than you want, you can just do

```
$myarray = $results[0];
```

and you have it.

update: per Chris Sprauge's comment: ARRAY_A is a WP constant which you have to give as it is. It is not an associative array parameter.

Comment: FYI for anybody wondering what ARRAY_A is ... it's a WordPress constant, not an array you have to pass