# Display the inserted data in wordpress custom template

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

Hi I am developing a word press website. I created a custom template, where in I have a form and fields are inserted into the database(mySql).  The Codes are shown below.`Insert into database`

Now I require to display the data which are already inserted into the database in front end in form of a `table` or `grid`. How I am able to do that.

I need the output something like this.

```
      Ritual Name   Ritual Active
      ---------------------------
      Test1        |    Y
      Test2        |    Y
```

Any help appreciated.

function.php

```
function childtheme_style_andscripts(){
    //wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-function',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .   '/js/ajaxfunction.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-function', 'usersubmitform', array(
'url'=> admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'security'=> wp_create_nonce('our-nonce')
    ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','childtheme_style_andscripts');

function form_action_function() {
    require_once(dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../../../wp-load.php');
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    global $wpdb;
    if( !check_ajax_referer('our-nonce', 'security' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error('security failed');
        return;
    }
    //var_dump($data);
    $rname=$data['rname'];
    $ractive=$data['ractive'];

    $table_name = "rituals";
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array ('Ritual_Name' => $rname, 'Ritual_Active' => $ractive) );

    //$wpdb->show_errors();
    //$wpdb->print_error();
    echo 'From Submitted Successfully';
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_form_action_function','form_action_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_form_action_function','form_action_function');
```

ajaxfunction.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var submitButton = document.getElementById('usersubmit');
var ajaxFunctionformprocess = function(fromdata, action){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: usersubmitform.url,
        data:{
            action:action,
            data:fromdata,
            security:usersubmitform.security,               
        },
        success:function(reponse){
            $('div.msg').html(reponse);
        },
        error:function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });     
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var fromdata = {
        'rname':document.getElementById('rname').value,
        'ractive':document.getElementById('ractive').value,
    };
    ajaxFunctionformprocess(fromdata, 'form_action_function');  

    }); 
  });
```

Samplepage.php(custom template)

```
  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <h1 class="headingform">User Form</h1>
        <div class="msg"></div>
        <form  class="userform">
            Ritual Name: <input type="text" id="rname" name="rname" /><br> <br>
            Ritual Active: <input type="text" id="ractive" name="ractive" /> <br><br> 
            <input  id="usersubmit"type="submit" Value="Submit" />
        </form>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065600/creating-an-associative-array-from-wordpress-wpdb-get-results check that second answer

Comment: bounty not rewarded

Comment: can you please tell me what you actually need in editor?

Comment: @VasimVanzara In editor i need a pop up form which contains many details. and the pop up should appear when i click the button which i have in visual editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1 :Create a template for display information  from table**

```
<?php
/*

Template Name: Disply Ritural
Description: display ritual information in table formate

*/


global $wpdb;
$table_name = "rituals";

$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM  $table_name");


foreach ( $result as $ritual_info )
{
        echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Name'];
        echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Active'];
}
```

**Case 2 :Create a shortcode make it easy to use.open your functions.php file add code there.**

```
function show_ritual_info(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = "rituals";
$query="SELECT * FROM  $table_name";
$result = $wpdb->get_results ($query);


foreach ( $result as $ritual_info )
{
        echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Name'];
        echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Active'];
}

}
add_shortcode('show_ritual_info','show_ritual_info');
```

**How to use shortcode**

- Inside php file

  `<?php echo do_shortcode('[show_ritual_info]'); ?>`
- Inside admin page

  `['show_ritual_info']`

Comment: i am getting these warnings
`Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-4.7\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php on line 205

Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-4.7\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php on line 213

Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #2 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-4.7\wordpress\wp-includes\shortcodes.php on line 214
Array`

Comment: i am using case 2

Comment: in functions .php i have placed this code `function show_ritual_info(){
require_once(dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
$table_name = "rituals";

$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM  $table_name");
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();

foreach ( $result as $ritual_info )
{
        echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Name'];
        echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Active'];
}

}
add_shortcode('show_ritual_info','show_ritual_info');`

Comment: and in custom template i have added this `<?php
 echo do_shortcode(['show_ritual_info']);
?>`

Comment: `function show_ritual_info(){

global $wpdb;
$table_name = "rituals";
$result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM  $table_name");
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();

//foreach ( $result as $ritual_info )
//{
       echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Name'];
       echo $ritual_info['Ritual_Active'];
//}

}
add_shortcode('show_ritual_info','show_ritual_info');`

Comment: $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
replace  with below code

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM $table_name";
echo $query; exit;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ($query);

Comment: when i echo the query i get `select * from rituals`  but when i remove the echo i get database error

Comment: `wpdb Object ( [show_errors] => [suppress_errors] => [last_error] => [num_queries] => 95 [num_rows] => 56 [rows_affected] ....and so on.`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = "rituals";
        // this will get the data from your table
        $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
        ?>
        <?php if( ! empty($retrieve_data) ):?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                 <th>Ritual Name</th>
                 <th>Ritual Active</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $retrieved_data['Ritual_Name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $retrieved_data['Ritual_Active'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Not check but must work.)